# Cannot install Kiviy by MinGW

Tags: python, mingw, kivy

I want to install Kivy module via MinGW compiler, but I get the following error :

> NameError: global name 'no_cygwin' is not defined

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and Python 2.7

What am I supposed to do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to downloading the kivy distribution zip file, you can install the kivy requirements into an existing 32 or 64 bit Python installation.

An unofficial pre-built binary windows installer is available at www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy

Otherwise, you can follow these instructions to build kivy from source:

For this example we'll assume you have Python installed in `

```
C:\dev\python27:
```

You need a MinGW installation. You can use the MinGW directory included in the kivy distribution or download a fresh MinGW. If you're compiling for 64 bit you'll need to the download the 64 bit MinGW (see here for how to setup a 64 bit mingw).

If you want to use gstreamer, copy it from the kivy distribution directory.

Get the kivy.bat file from the kivy distribution, or alternatively set the path and other environmental variables as in the kivy.bat file in order to have a permanent setup. You'll have to execute the following instructions from this environment.

You'll need to edit the paths first to point to the correct python and MinGW locations. If you started with a clean MinGW installation you'll also have to add to the path the location of make.exe if you will be doing any kivy development.

Download and install distutils and pip. You can install both using the ez_setup.py and get_pip.py files from www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html.

In `C:\dev\python27\Lib\distutils` create a empty distutils.cfg file. In the file type:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

Download and install cython by typing:

pip install cython
Download Glew 1.5.7 from www.sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/. Install the Glew files into the following locations:

```
glew32.dll -> C:\dev\python27
glew32.dll -> MinGW\lib
glew32.lib -> MinGW\lib
glew32s.lib -> MinGW\lib
glew.h -> MinGW\include\GL
glxew.h -> MinGW\include\GL
wglew.h -> MinGW\include\GL
```

If you get errors when installing kivy such as GL/glew.h: No such file or directory, which is likely to happen with the 64 bit mingw, you'll need to copy the GL directory and its contents into python27/include and the *.dll and *.lib files from above into python27/libs. If you still get errors then type the following to generate the .a file:

```
cd C:\dev\Python27\libs
rename glew32.lib old_glew32.lib
rename glew32s.lib old_glew32s.lib
gendef glew32.dll
dlltool --dllname glew32.dll --def glew32.def --output-lib libglew32.a
```

Download and install the precompiled Pygame 1.9.2 binaries from www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame.

Finally, to install the latest kivy, type:

```
pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/zipball/master
```

Alternatively instead of the githup zipball you can point to a specific kivy zip file. Also, if you have a development version of kivy and want to continue working on it while still installing it you can use the pip --editable switch e.g.:

```
pip install --editable C:\dev\kivy
```

This will put a link in the site-packages directory pointing to your kivy source, so any changes in the source will be reflected in the install. See here for more details: www.pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode.